# Google Analytics - how to track an internal page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to figure out how I can track certain pages within a website, which open on click within a page with URL 12345.com and look like 12345.com#54321 (different endings). GA cannot be seen on these pages. Is there a way to track these pages?

Comment: could you clarify, what do you mean by "GA cannot be seen on these pages"?

1.
you can't put GA/GTM code there? 

2.
or you don't see them in reports?

Comment: There's no tracking since these are ancor links as Bronwyn V kindly explained in the next comment)

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics does not track anchor links out of the box, you will need to edit the tracking code.
**Try the following**
**If using Universal analytics.js**, edit from this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

**to this:**

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': location.pathname + location.search + location.hash});
```

**If using gtag.js**, edit from this:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');
```

**to this:**

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
  'page_path': location.pathname + location.search + location.hash
  });
```

Comment: Many thanks for clarification! My GA account is implemented via GTM. Is there a way to deal with it with GTM?

Comment: In GTM try to:
1. Create custom JavaScript variable with simple function (using fragment of @Bronwyn V code) (name it e.g: "my_location"): 

function() {
 return location.search + location.hash;
}


 2. Then modify your Google Analytics tag (or other ga tags too): in tag select more options and set new custom field. Field should be named: "page" (GTM will give you tips for field name)  and then in field value type: {{Page Path}}{{my_location}}

3. Save tag and debug it - should work.

Comment: Rather than duplication of effort I replied to your other thread that i had also responded to over on the google GA help community

Comment: @BronwynV Thanks a lot, the link provided in GA help community (https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-url-fragments-as-pageviews/) was very useful and helped!

Comment: If you're using GTM, edit your GA tag, then check the "Enable overriding settings in this tag" checkbox to display fields.  Then like Jacek said, add "page" and a reference to your variable that grabs the page #id reference.  Here's the custom JS variable I used: 
function() {
  return window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;
}

So the value for the field is "page" and {{your_variable_name}}